# WSO2 : Determining that a message contains a specific element or not

Tags: soap, wso2, esb

How can i determine that a message contains a specific element? i want to enrich the message if it does not contain specific element, but i do not know how to determine it?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Filter+Mediator) to perform content based mediation. Following sample shows your usecase. (1) The filtering was done using the xpath matching. It searches for NOT occurrence of XPath //p:echoString/test, and performs enrich mediation based on that. Following soap body will match the filter. (2)

(1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="messageFilter" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full" separator=","/>
            <filter xpath="not(//p:echoString/test)" xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org" >
                <then>
                    <log separator=",">
                        <property name="XPath Matched" value="true"/>
                    </log>
                    <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" xpath="//p:echoString/in"/>
                        <target type="property" property="ORIGINAL_REQ"/>
                    </enrich>
                    <log separator=",">
                        <property name="ORIGINAL_REQ" expression="get-property('ORIGINAL_REQ')"/>
                    </log>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <log separator=",">
                        <property name="XPath Matched" value="false"/>
                    </log>
                </else>
            </filter>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://localhost:9763/services/echo"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full" separator=",">
                <property name="OUT-SEQUENCE" value="property_value"/>
            </log>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

(2)

```
<body>
   <p:echoString xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
      <in>123</in>
      <test>testing-node</test>
   </p:echoString>
</body>
```